# Indicate legend in R barplot properly

Tags: r, bar-chart, yaxis

I saw a few postings where people ask how to indicate the legend of their plots properly. However, all of these people had enough space in their margins to shift the legend. In my case, I do not have that much space because of my two lines I plotted using abline demand the whole space. Can someone tell me how to place my legend, e.g. over the two lines (also other ideas are greatly appreciated).

```
h1 <- 174
h2 <- 122

data.mlm = matrix(
   c(125,125,116,99,83,68,58,45,33,32,18,12,7,60,82,74,60,49,41,34,29,19,22,8,7,4),
   nrow=2,              # number of rows 
   ncol=13,              # number of columns 
   byrow = TRUE) 


colnames(data.mlm) <- c("1","2","3", "4","5","6", "7","8","9", "10","11","12", "13")
rownames(data.mlm) <- c("100% Sample","MLM Sample")


barplot(data.mlm, 
        col=colors()[c(180, 1)] , 
        border="black", 
        font.axis=1, 
        beside=T, 
        ylim=(c(0, 200)),
        legend=rownames(data.mlm), 
        xlab="Measurement point",
        ylab="Number of observations per measurement point",
        font.lab=1,)



abline(122, 0, lty=2)
abline(174, 0, lty=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```r
 barplot(data.mlm, 
        col=colors()[c(180, 1)] , 
        border="black", 
        font.axis=1, 
        beside=T, 
        ylim=(c(0, 200)),
        #legend=rownames(data.mlm), 
        xlab="Measurement point",
        ylab="Number of observations per measurement point",
        font.lab=1,)

legend("right", legend=c("100% Sample", "MLM Sample"),
       col=colors()[c(180, 1)], fill=colors()[c(180, 1)], cex=0.8)


abline(122, 0, lty=2)
abline(174, 0, lty=2)
```

Which positions the legend to the right of the plot: 
[image: bar_legend_right]

Answer (score 1):

here is a manual change to stop the one line from crossing the legend. Only the last line of code was changed

```
h1 <- 174
h2 <- 122

data.mlm = matrix(
  c(125,125,116,99,83,68,58,45,33,32,18,12,7,60,82,74,60,49,41,34,29,19,22,8,7,4),
  nrow=2,              # number of rows 
  ncol=13,              # number of columns 
  byrow = TRUE) 


colnames(data.mlm) <- c("1","2","3", "4","5","6", "7","8","9", "10","11","12", "13")
rownames(data.mlm) <- c("100% Sample","MLM Sample")


barplot(data.mlm, 
        col=colors()[c(180, 1)] , 
        border="black", 
        font.axis=1, 
        beside=T, 
        ylim=(c(0, 200)),
        legend=rownames(data.mlm), 
        args.legend = c(bg='white'),
        xlab="Measurement point",
        ylab="Number of observations per measurement point",
        font.lab=1,)



abline(122, 0, lty=2)
lines(c(0,25),c(174,174), lty=2)
```

Comment: I actually added the line 'args.legend = c(bg='white')' as well as my first try of a solution. It can be removed since the transparency of the legend was not the problem. The lines get called after the legend has already been created.